# Lua Error 'for' limit must be a number

Tags: loops, for-loop, types, lua, numbers

I'm working on a scanner plugin that loops through a range of various channels in increments of up to 32.
I'm new to Lua. 
Tables, tables everywhere.
I did not know Lua did not do +=, ++. 
i = i + 1 -- flashbacks.

I'm running into this variable type error,

```
plugins/scanner/main.lua:136: 'for' limit must be a number
```

and i've checked my variable types. both say they're numbers.

right now i'm working on getting the incremental loops running smoothly.

here's the link to the code :
http://codepad.org/Dc3jBBrx

thanks again, stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's probably just a typo on line 136

Scanner.innerRrangeMax  should be Scanner.innerRangeMax

e.g line 136 is

```
for i = Scanner.innerRangeMin, Scanner.innerRrangeMax do
```

try

```
for i = Scanner.innerRangeMin, Scanner.innerRangeMax do
```

Comment: O M G. tyty so much! i guess one can't roll the r's.
could be time to apply an IDE.